# Wifi error after Motorola XOOM tablet Android 4.0.4 update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, motorola-droid, motorola-xoom

I have a Motorola XOOM type tablet.
Three days ago I updated my tablet to Android 4.0.4.
But after that I can't connect to my wi-fi modem.

I was successfully connecting before this update. I also tried with my desktop computer and ipad, they can connect.

I resetted modem. Checked for firware update- no update. Changed password. Restarted several types but they didn't help.
How can I fix this WI-FI issue?

Comment: Get [alogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) and see the logs for incriminating output. Post findings here.

Answer (score 0):

It is affecting every Xoom.  It appears there is an error with the update, it basically bricks your xoom.  My has the same issue and now the Xoom is useless.